# Datastax Cassandra SSL

Tags: ssl, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and just installed DataStax Community Edition 3-node cluster in our QA environment. I'd like to secure node-to-node and client-to-node communications within my cluster using GlobalSign wildcard SSL cert that I already have. So far I found posts showing how to secure cluster using your own CA but wasn't able to find any mentions on how to use wildcard certs. Basically, I'd like to install my wildcard cert to all nodes in the cluster and use DNS A-records to match node IP address and the DNS name (e.g. 10.100.1.1 > node01.domain.com).

Is that even possible? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Using anything but certificate pinning as described in the [reference](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureSSLCertificates_t.html) is insecure, as Cassandra will not validate if the hostname the certificate was created for is actually the host trying to connect. See [CASSANDRA-9220](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9220) for details.